# How to get text to display in a TextBrowser in Qt?

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface, qt4

I am new to c++ and even newer to Qt on Linux.
Can any one give me a general idea of how to display text in a textbrowser in Qt?  I can't post my code because of the seative nature of the project I am working on.  All I need is a basic understanding of how to do this related to slots and signals.

My application is this:  I am taking input from a CSV file, counting the ords and then displaying the number of counted words along with the line of text in an output window.
It works fine in  console c++ program.  However, when I code it in Qt, it does not work.

Any advise or help would be welcome.

Comment: You don't have to post your whole application, or even a snippet from it. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: can you please clarify your comment above?

Comment: Create simple code that reproduces the problem. We don't need to know anything more.

Comment: Ah, the secretive nature of a project where words are counted? Give me a break. We won't do your school homework for you. Qt has plenty of tutorials and examples. You have to go through them yourself. If your code doesn't work, show it. I don't believe you have any code. Sorry. Otherwise you'd have told us *what* doesn't work.

Comment: Kubar -- it is not a school project ... trust me ...

Comment: Kamil -- I will work on doing that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the bad question I asked earlier.
It turns out it was a configuration issue on my part.